# Bucle contador PHP con un foreach

Tags: php, bucles

Tengo este código que me genera una lista de los posts mejor puntuados y funciona perfecto.

```
echo "<div class='col-md-10'>";
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ($posts as $post)
    {
       echo "<li class='f$post->ID'><a href='".get_permalink($post->ID)."'>".$post->post_title."</a>";
       if($sr)
       {
           $best = get_option('kksr_stars');
           echo " <span class='toprat' style='font-size:10px;'>".$post->ratings."</span>";
       }
       echo "</li>";
    }
    echo '</ul>';
    echo "</div>";
```

Esto me genera algo así:

Título de un post  10.0puntos

Título de otro post  8.0puntos
...

Me gustaría crear dentro del bucle un contador que fuera cambiando para que cada vez que se ejecutara **mostrara la posición al lado**. Ejemplo:

1º Título de un post  10.0puntos

2º Título de otro post  8.0puntos
...

Tengo los bucles un poco oxidados y no hago más que cargarme el código, si alguien puede orientarme se lo agradezco.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intenta con:

```
echo "<div class='col-md-10'>";
echo '<ul>';
foreach ($posts as $position => $post)
{
   echo "<li class='f$post->ID'><a href='".get_permalink($post->ID)."'>".($position+1)."º ".$post->post_title."</a>";
   if($sr)
   {
       $best = get_option('kksr_stars');
       echo " <span class='toprat' style='font-size:10px;'>".$post->ratings."</span>";
   }
   echo "</li>";
}
echo '</ul>';
echo "</div>";
```

De esta forma el foreach regresa el índice de cada elemento del array. Solo basta sumarle uno e imprimirlo en pantalla.

Comment: Perfecto subtituyéndolo por el código anterior. Muchas gracias.